# How to determine if object is a class or a function in Javascript

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

Say I have these two:

```
class Foo {}
const Bar = function() {}

// Then somewhere I have an object:
const variable = Foo;
// OR
const variable = Bar;
```

How can I know if `variable` is a function or a class? The problem here is that `typeof Foo` or `typeof Bar` both return `function`.

Comment: object is object ;-)

Comment: @johnSmith :( :D. So there is no way?!

Comment: sure, but what you describe are variables, just use `typeof`

Comment: @johnSmith but `typeof Foo` or `typeof Bar` would both return `function` ...

Comment: @Kousha Wait a second, what's the question? To distinguish between a class and function's type, or to check if a variable is either a class or function?

Comment: @AndrewLi how?! `typeof` of both would return `function`

Comment: There are no "classes" in javascript. There is a class syntax. All native functions are constructors, there is no way to tell them apart. However, in the latest versions of ECMAScript, constructors created using the Class syntax will throw an error if called as a function, so there is that.

Comment: @Kousha Why exactly do you care what it is, and why do you need to decide dynamically?

Comment: @Bergi looks like an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem).

Comment: @EmileBergeron yes indeed, that's why I'm asking

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*This question was to be expected with the confusion caused by the new syntactic sugar added recently.*

From the [MDN doc on Classes](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Classes):

> JavaScript classes introduced in ECMAScript 2015 are primarily
>   syntactical sugar over JavaScript's existing prototype-based
>   inheritance. The class syntax is **not** introducing a new object-oriented
>   inheritance model to JavaScript.
>   [...]
>   Classes are in fact "special [functions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions)", and just as you can define
>   [function expressions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/function) and [function declarations](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/function), the class syntax has
>   two components: [class expressions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/class) and [class declarations](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/class).

The [MDN doc on class expressions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/class) shows what you already know about `typeof`:

```
'use strict';
var Foo = class {}; // constructor property is optional
var Foo = class {}; // Re-declaration is allowed

typeof Foo; //returns "function"
typeof class {}; //returns "function"

Foo instanceof Object; // true
Foo instanceof Function; // true
class Foo {}; // Throws TypeError, doesn't allow re-declaration
```

> But unlike the class expression, the [class declaration](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/class) doesn't allow an
>   existing class to be declared again and will throw a type error if
>   attempted.
>   [...]
>   Class declarations are not hoisted (unlike [function declarations](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/function)).